# when i run createsuperuser getting HTTP 401 error

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

Am using Django-nonrel and appengine for my app. user login/logout, user creation everything works fine in local server. But when i try to create remote user it fails with following error.

command:

```
    python manage.py remote createsuperuser
```

Error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 444, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 527, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...

All i was suppose to change was 
"Authentication Type" to Google accounts api in appengine dashboard.

In my case it was "Federated Login"